# How does $(xy' + x'y)'$ simplify to $(xy + x'y')$

Tags: boolean-algebra

How does

$$(xy' + x'y)'$$

simplify to

$$(xy + x'y')$$

Comment: @FlybyNight: Since the question is tagged [tag:boolean-algebra] it is probably the Boolean-algebra negation.

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By de Morgan laws :
$$(xy'+x'y)'=(x'+y)(x+y')=x'x+x'y'+yx+yy'=xy+x'y'$$
because $xx'=yy'=0$.

(BTW, I suppose $x'$ means $\overline x$, or $\neg x$...)

Comment: Ah I see, this helped a lot, thank you.